# read Mutli-Format data file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a data file that looks likes this:

> some_words 
>   some words | more words 
>   1 2 3 4 
>   1 2 3 4 
>   1 2 3 4 
>   
>   
>   some_other_words 
>   some words | moar words 
>   1 2 3 4 
>   1 2 3 4 
>   1 2 3 4

What I would like to do is read in only the numbers, ignoring the line breaks and text in the file without having to use `fgetl` and iterate line by line. if I do: 

`data = textscan(fileId,'%f%f%f%f','CellectOutput',false,'Headerlines',2)`
 
The data reads in the first block of text but stops when it gets to the line break. The line break is ALWAYS 2 lines long. Not sure if that helps out at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
id = fopen('fgetl.m');

tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    disp(tline)
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```

to read the entire file, or:

```
clc;
fid = fopen('fileName.m');
sl = 2;
for i=1:sl
  header = fgetl(fid);
  disp(strcat("Header ignored: ",header));
end

while ischar(tline)
    disp(strcat("Line imported: ",tline))
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```

to ignore the first 2 lines and import the rest, you should save or do whatever you want with the value of "tline" variable inside the while loop. **Important CHANGE the value of "sl" variable for the number of lines you want to ignore in your file.** It works for any plain text file.